# "allowed" operations in bash read while loop

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I have a file `text.txt` which contains two lines.

```
first line
second line
```

I am trying to loop in bash using following loop:

```
while read -r LINE || [[ -n "$LINE" ]]; do
   # sed -i 'some command' somefile
   echo "echo something"
   echo "$LINE"
   sh call_other_script.sh

   if  ! sh some_complex_script.sh   ; then
        echo "operation failed"
   fi

done <file.txt
```

When calling `some_complex_script.sh` **only the first line is processed**, however when commenting it out  all two lines are processed.
`some_complex_script.sh` does all kind of stuff, like starting processes, sqlplus, starting WildFly etc.

```
./bin/call_some_script.sh | tee $SOME_LOGFILE &
wait

...

sqlplus  $ORACLE_USER/$ORACLE_PWD@$DB<<EOF
whenever sqlerror exit 1;
whenever oserror exit 2;
INSERT INTO TABLE ....
COMMIT;

quit;
EOF

...
nohup $SERVER_DIR/bin/standalone.sh -c $WILDFLY_PROFILE -u 230.0.0.4 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

My question is **if there are some operations which are not supposed to  be called** in `some_complex_script.sh` and in **the loop** (it may as well take 10 minutes to finish, is this a good idea at all?) which may break that loop. 
The script is called using Jenkins and the [Publish over SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin). When `some_complex_script.sh` is called on its own, there are no problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should close or redirect stdin for the other commands you run, to stop them reading from the file. eg:

```
 sh call_other_script.sh </dev/null
```